# How do you build or modify the user interface for an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, user-interface

What application is used for creating iPhone user interfaces?

Do you write code for layout, is there a css-esque system in place etc?

Or is it more like creating a winforms application where you drop in the elements in a visual designer?

Is it difficult to modify the appearing of an existing iPhone application, say to change the graphics used for buttons, and background colours on certain screens etc?

**Additonal Info**

The reason I ask is that I have a Blackberry application that I want converted to an iPhone application, and I need to know if I have to tell the developer translating it to build it in a certain way, as I need to be able to change the graphical appearance of this app.

I need to be able to change any background colours, logo, and the buttons used. Not sure if the iPhone uses images for "buttons" on the GUI?

Answer (score 2):

You can either create UI completely in code, or use the Interface Builder visual tool to create pre-made UI objects, or any mix of the two.  You can also modify an object loaded from an IB .xib file in your app's code.

To modify stuff created in code, you would need to edit the code and recompile.  To modify objects created in interface builder, you would still need to rebuild the app (assuming stock tools and OS) with those new objects.

Comment: Does this need to be decided when starting to build the app? I need the easiest way to be able to modify the appearance of the app once built, as i'm getting another developer to convert my Blackberry App and need to be able to modify the appearance as easily as possible. I have access to a Mac when it comes to doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Interface Builder, something like visual designer you said, to create xib (xml based) file for the UI. You can also create UI manually by code.

If you're more familiar to using css to layout UI elements, you can make a site for safari fitting the device's resolution, or put things into a html string and load it into a UIWebView.

You're able to modify the graphics, but you cannot put the app back to your phone unless you JBed you phone.